# scrapy/selectorlib error while crawling amazon

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, python-3.6

I'm trying to scrape amazon's offers page (www.amazon.it/gp/goldbox) using scrapy and selectorlib

Here is my spider's code:

**amazon.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import os
import selectorlib

class AmazonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'amazon'
    allowed_domains = ['www.amazon.it']
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.it/gp/goldbox']
    # Create Extractor for listing page
    listing_page_extractor = selectorlib.Extractor.from_yaml_file(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'../selectorlib_yaml/urlSelector.yml'))
    # Create Extractor for product page
    product_page_extractor = selectorlib.Extractor.from_yaml_file(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'../selectorlib_yaml/selector.yml'))

    def parse(self, response):
        # Extract data using Extractor
        data = self.listing_page_extractor.extract(response.text)
        if 'next' in data:
            # Printing for debug
            print(data['next'])
            yield scrapy.Request(data['next'],callback=self.parse)
        for p in data['product_page']:
            yield scrapy.Request(p,callback=self.parse_product)

    def parse_product(self, response):
        # Extract data using Extractor
        product = self.product_page_extractor.extract(response.text)
        if product:
            yield product
```

By running scrapy crawl `spidername`, I get an error `TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got list:`

I'm not pasting the whole error just because the problem is with **selectorlib**, which is returning an empty list (`print(data['next'])` returns just `[]`). I am sure that the yml files are ok, since I created them with the *selectorlib* chrome extension and they worked just fine. but if you want to try and reproduce the error, here they are:

**urlSelector.yml**

```
product_page:
    css: a.a-size-base
    multiple: true
    type: Link
next:
    css: 'div#pagination-next-30159412167606625.a-text-center li.a-last a'
    type: Link
```

**selector.yml**

```
title:
    css: h1.a-size-large
    type: Text
category:
    css: 'div.a-subheader a.a-link-normal'
    multiple: true
    type: Text
price:
    css: 'td.a-span12 span.a-size-medium.a-color-price'
    type: Text
delivery:
    css: 'span.a-size-medium span.a-size-base'
    type: Text
fullprice:
    css: span.priceBlockStrikePriceString
    type: Text
discount:
    css: td.a-span12.a-color-price
    type: Text
availability:
    css: 'div.a-section div.feature div.a-section div.a-section span.a-size-medium'
    type: Text
time:
    css: 'td.a-span12 div.a-row span.a-size-base.a-color-base'
    type: Text
promotion:
    css: 'div.a-popover-content li'
    type: Text
stars:
    css: 'div.a-icon-row span.a-size-medium, div.a-popover-content span.a-size-base a.a-link-normal'
    multiple: true
    type: Text
votes:
    css: 'span.a-declarative a.a-link-normal span.a-size-base'
    multiple: true
    type: Text
ASIN:
    css: 'div.column.col2 tr:nth-of-type(1) td.value'
    type: Text
image:
    css: img.fullscreen
    multiple: true
    type: Attribute
    attribute: src
description:
    css: 'div.a-row div.a-section p:nth-of-type(1)'
    type: Text
```

What do I have to do to make selectorlib extract the values properly?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting problem, looks like Amazon is making harder and harder to parse their responses, mostly because everyone wants the data they publicly share.

Here there are 3 interesting things Amazon is doing, which you'll have to debug more clearly:

- The html structure is being created dynamically, the response body is not actually parseable html (you get those css with the selectorlib chrome extension, because chrome has already done all the work of reformatting the response body with javascript, remember scrapy is not a browser, it has handles simple plain text from the request responses).
- The pagination link identifiers (in your case: `div#pagination-next-30159412167606625`) are also being created dynamically, that number is randomly being generated on loading time. You can check it reloading the site and checking that number changes every time.
- The pagination link is also being generated dynamically, the link you were trying to find is not in the element you were trying to find (the next page element), it is actually being created with javascript and a json-parseable element is being called and it's repopulating the site.

I am sorry I can't be able to provide actual code and more direction on how to solve your problem, but understanding and creating the actual spider will take a lot of coding work.

Answer (score 0):

As @eLRuLL mentioned, pagination div id generated dynamically.

You have to use some driver to render javascript on the page, like headless browser. Or [scrapy-recommended](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html#pre-rendering-javascript) Splash.

```
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
...

for p in data['product_page']:
    yield SplashRequest(p,
                        callback=self.parse_product,
                        args={'wait': 0,5},
                        endpoint = 'render.html')
```

With selectorlib you can use xpath selector, contains 'pagination-next'.

https://selectorlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#xpath-default-blank

urlSelector.yml

```
product_page:
    css: a.a-size-base
    multiple: true
    type: Link
next:
    xpath: '//div[contains(@id, "pagination-next")]//li[@class="a-last"]/a/@href'
    type: Link
```

Comment: right, that is the `xpath` "if the page was dynamically generated, but this is a `scrapy` question, so that won't work when parsing the response body directly as I explained.

If you choose to redo how you crawl sites, an decide to use a browser emulator (like selenium), then this will work.

Comment: thanks for a comment, I added example using Splash to answer